# Is there any internet browser supporting input="datetime" by a datetime picker?

Tags: html, datetime

Is there any internet browser which will provide a datetime(not only date) picker for this HTML field:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date of Birth must be a date." data-val-required="Pole Date of Birth jest wymagane." id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" type="datetime" value="2014-08-07 00:00:00">
```

I have tried:

- IE 11
- Opera 24
- Chrome 37
- Current Safari
- Torch
- Netscape Navigator

Comment: when in doubt the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) are great resource. `datetime` is timezone specific, `datetime-local` is not

Comment: It says opera has it but it does not. It is weird that browsers does not support  that.